# How to remove quotations from JSON file while writing from PHP?

Tags: php, json

I currently have the following code which has an array, and outputs it into a JSON file called 'example.json'.

Below is the code that outputs to it:

```
$x = array(1, 2, 3); //Defining two basic arrays
$y = array(2, 4, 6);
$name = array("Joe", "John", "Johnny");
echo count($x);
$objOne = '["type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [';
file_put_contents("jsonfun.json", json_encode($objOne));
for($i = 0; $i < count($x); $i++)
{
    $objTwo = '{ "type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [' . $x[$i] . ', ' . $y[$i] . ']}, "properties": {"name": ' . $name[$i] . '} }]';
    file_put_contents("jsonfun.json", json_encode($objTwo), FILE_APPEND);
}
$objThree = '};';
file_put_contents("jsonfun.json", json_encode($objThree), FILE_APPEND);
```

Output:

```
"[\"type\": \"FeatureCollection\", \"features\": [""{ \"type\": \"Feature\", \"geometry\": {\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [1, 2]}, \"properties\": {\"name\": Joe} }]""{ \"type\": \"Feature\", \"geometry\": {\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [2, 4]}, \"properties\": {\"name\": John} }]""{ \"type\": \"Feature\", \"geometry\": {\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [3, 6]}, \"properties\": {\"name\": Johnny} }]""};"
```

As you may have seen there are a lot of slashes which I don't know where they came from... and likewise there are also several quotations where they shouldn't be;

Should look like:

```
"[type...
```

Is there any chance I could remove those, or am I doing it wrong? I have tried multiple things, such as doing `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` or simply typing the string in different ways but nothing has worked.

Comment: Why are you trying to construct the json yourself? Use the in-built functions (*`json_encode()`/`json_decode()`*).

Comment: JSON_HEX_APOS JSON_HEX_QUOT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you're not encoding an array / object with `json_encode`, instead you're writing a string that you manually built.  [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) encodes JSON from an *array*, *object*, or *collection*.  Not from strings.

```
// This is a string, and will not json_encode properly
$objOne = '["type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [';
file_put_contents("jsonfun.json", json_encode($objOne));

// This is an ARRAY, and will encode properly
$objOne = array( 'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
                 'features' => array(
                        'featureOne',
                        'featureTwo'
                 )
          );

file_put_contents("jsonfun.json", json_encode($objOne));
// Will result in contents of
// {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":["featureOne","featureTwo"]}
```

Comment: And we have a winner! This is the solution. (*may be worth noting it's throwing in the slashes because he's trying to `json_encode()` a json string*)

Comment: Thank you, any recommended tutorials on how to dynamically populate a JSON file from mySQL data? I am still having some troubles.

Comment: @Ricky - have you seen this article? http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/01/convert-mysql-to-json-using-php.html